# There was an error importing a wsdl binding that the wsdl port is dependent on

Tags: asp.net-core, wsdl

We are using asp core to add WCF Service

but we are getting this error

> "Cannot import wsdl:port
> Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on.
> XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace=':binding[@name='AAResWebServicesHttpBinding']"

The only reason why we tried to add the WSDL service is that we want to generate XML files and below is a sample from the XML That we trying to generate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soap:Header>
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" soap:mustUnderstand="1">
         <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="XXXX">
            <wsse:Username>XXX</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">XXXX</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body xmlns:ns1="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
      <ns1:OTA_AirAvailRQ EchoToken="11868765275150-1300257933" PrimaryLangID="en-us" SequenceNmbr="1" TimeStamp="2012-08-27T03:00:23" Version="20061.00" Target="TEST">
         <ns1:POS>
            <ns1:Source TerminalID="XXXX">
               <ns1:RequestorID ID="XXXX" Type="XXXX" />
               <ns1:BookingChannel Type="12" />
            </ns1:Source>
         </ns1:POS>
         <ns1:OriginDestinationInformation>
            <ns1:DepartureDateTime WindowAfter="P1D" WindowBefore="P1D">2023-01-20T10:00:00</ns1:DepartureDateTime>
            <ns1:OriginLocation LocationCode="BOM" />
            <ns1:DestinationLocation LocationCode="SHJ" />
         </ns1:OriginDestinationInformation>
         <ns1:OriginDestinationInformation>
            <ns1:DepartureDateTime WindowAfter="P1D" WindowBefore="P1D">2023-01-25T10:00:00</ns1:DepartureDateTime>
            <ns1:OriginLocation LocationCode="SHJ" />
            <ns1:DestinationLocation LocationCode="BOM" />
         </ns1:OriginDestinationInformation>
         <ns1:TravelerInfoSummary>
            <ns1:AirTravelerAvail>
               <ns1:PassengerTypeQuantity Code="ADT" Quantity="3" />
               <ns1:PassengerTypeQuantity Code="CHD" Quantity="1" />
            </ns1:AirTravelerAvail>
         </ns1:TravelerInfoSummary>
      </ns1:OTA_AirAvailRQ>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How to solve such an error or how can we generate the same sample from our c# code?

We checked with WSDL help desk if there is any error on the link, but they mentioned they don't have any error and the WSDL files are working fine, the error is from your said only, also we tried to generate the XML Without adding the WSDL Service but we got an error message in saying that

> WSS4JInHandler: Request does not contain required Security header

as we searched we found out that we didn't add the "WASE" In the header but according for what we searched we have to add the reference for the WSDL First so that we can send it with the "WASE"

Comment: Could you please share, how this `xml` has been genereated? In which step you are getting the error? While adding service on asp.net core project or when?

Comment: For the Above XML, I have hard codded it, which means I Have typed it  manually and it works if I am testing it from the postman, but when I tried to generate the same XML From my Code I got the same values but the header tag is not the same, especially the "wsse" tag, so I tried to the Given WSDL Link but I got this error, and to honest with you even if I am have successfully added the WSDL Into the link still I have no idea how I can generate such XML With these tags "wsse" 
@MdFaridUddinKiron

Comment: Well, thanks for your response. Considering your scenario, what `XML` you would like to generate programetically, please share that one. In addition, please include your current snippet where you are struggling with.

Comment: the XML That I want to generate  is this (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xGyF35tD3wzTmZxJvPT6RtQU6nWMprFB/view?usp=sharing)

but from my code I am getting this XML 

(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UUKtgxp45VmYl0AiUgEyFzA16_aFmokn/view?usp=sharing)

you can find my code below 
(https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wUYvU1p5ghQv8pbYaTXHyhkBcxhRpW1T/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=116860538947184597824&rtpof=true&sd=true)

@MdFaridUddinKiron